# How to use a value from function x for constructors in functions y

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger

I have the function `NodeTransitionFunction(Integer exp, Integer KVal)` which needs to calculate `f(x) = (x ^ exp) % KVal`.

Then there is a function Integer apply(Integer val) which needs to calculate f(val).

Now to set the constructor for NodeTransitionFunction, how do I get the argument val from the apply function?

or am I completely trying to solve this the wrong way?

```
public class NodeTransitionFunction {

    public NodeTransitionFunction(Integer exp, Integer KVal) {
        // CONSTUCTOR: Sets the class to calculate f(x) = (x ^ exp) mod KVal 

        // TODO
    }

    public Integer apply(Integer val) {
        // PRE: -
        // POST: Implements f(val)
        // TODO

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeTransitionFunction f = new NodeTransitionFunction(3, 33);

        System.out.println(f.apply(5));
    }

}
```

Comment: Store the constructor arguments in private, non-static fields.

Comment: Do you need the function to be set in the constructor? Why can't you just calculate the result in the `apply` method?

Comment: This is a uni assignment, I'm not allowed to change the functions that are already there, I could add my own helper functions tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to pass a function to the constructor so that it can be later applied. If that's the case you don't really need a class at all: what you are defining is a `IntUnaryOperator` - i.e. a function that takes an int and returns an int.

So:

```
IntUnaryOperator makeNodeTransitionFunction(double exp, double mod) {
    return x -> Math.round(Math.mod(Math.power(x, exp), mod));
}
```

Then applying it as a matter of:

```
makeNodeTransitionFunction(7, 11).apply(5)
```

If you need it to be in a class then you can make the `IntUnaryOperator` a private field that is assigned in the constructor. The `apply` method would then just delegate to the field.

Comment: This is actually a uni assignment I'm working on, I can't change anything except add my own code, I can add helper methods if needed.

The reason I'm confused is that in the comments, the lecturer left this line:

// CONSTUCTOR: Sets the class to calculate f(x) = (x ^ exp) mod KVal

There are 3 variables that are needed to calculate f(x), x, exp and KVal. well I have exp and KVal in my arguments but x is given in the apply function.

So when I'm writing the constructor for NodeTransitionFunction, how do I represent x?

Comment: In future I suggest you add any of those types of restrictions to your question. I suspect your lecturer is expecting you to store the two variables in the constructor in object variables then use them in the apply method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  So what should I be searching for to find out how to do this? I'm still lost as to how to code this.